# How to tell if writing data to firestore has succeeded or not?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a cloud function to write data to a firestore document, and I need to send an HTTP response afterwards to inform the client whether the operation has succeeded or not
I want something like this:

```
const docRef = db.collection("users").doc("testUser");
docRef.set({
    name: "Test"
}).then(ref => {
   if (success) res.status(200).send("success");
   else res.status(500).send("failure");
});
```

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code that makes the HTTP response inside your existing `then` callback.  It will only be invoked when the write is successful at the server side.  It looks like you're already doing this, but there is no need to check anything called `success`.  Errors will be delivered to a `catch` callback, which you are not currently using.

This is pretty standard behavior for JavaScript promises.

Comment: The code inside `then` will execute if the write was successful, how about if it was not? where should I put the corresponding code?

Comment: As I said, in a `catch` callback.  You should get familiar with how promises work in JavaScript. This is all very standard programming practice. If you are new to JavaScript and Cloud Functions you might find some of these videos helpful.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: The problem here is that catch is called only in some cases (e.g. missing permissions). If the user is offline nothing is thrown. How do I catch this?

Comment: It's not an error to be offline at the time of a write.  The write will eventually be synchronized with the server when the device comes back online.